# CKEditor - allowedContent отключает плагин colorbutton

Tags: ckeditor

Установил в **CKEditor** плагин `colorbutton` (кнопка выбора цвета текста и фона), но, похоже, `allowedContent` его блокирует. Что нужно сюда добавить, чтобы плагин заработал? (он в код вставляет тег span, но добавление span ни к чему не приводит). Спасибо.

```
config.allowedContent = 'h2 h3 h4 p blockquote strong;' +
'a[href,name];' +
'img[!src,alt,width,height];' +
'ul li;' +
'ol li;' +
'table tr th td caption;';
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `'span[style];'`.

Comment: Пробовал - ничего. Мало того, если добавить к ссылке или к списками (т.е. вот так: 'a[href,name] span[style];' ) - исчезают соответствующие группы кнопок

Answer (score 1):

Все, получилось! Вот решение:

```
span{color,background-color};
```